# PyTorch Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I have the following PyTorch tensors:

```
predicted = torch.tensor([4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 4, 0, 4, 4, 1, 4, 1])

target    = torch.tensor([3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,])
```

I want to compute the Cross Entropy Loss (as part of an ***Logistic Regression*** implementation) between them with the following lines:

```
loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
computed_loss = loss(predicted, target)
```

However, when my code runs, I get the following ***IndexError***:

```
IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)
```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

/ ##################################################################### /

Here is the full TraceBack:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-208-3cdb253d6620> in <module>
      1 batch_size = 1000
      2 train_class = Train((training_set.shape[1]-1), number_of_target_labels, 0.01, 1000)
----> 3 train_class.train_model(training_set, batch_size)

<ipython-input-207-f3e2c7f7979a> in train_model(self, training_data, n_iters)
     42                 out = self.model(x)
     43                 _, predicted = torch.max(out.data, 1)
---> 44                 loss = self.criterion(predicted, y)
     45                 self.optimizer.zero_grad()
     46                 loss.backward()

/anaconda3/envs/malicious_ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    491             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    492         else:
--> 493             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    494         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    495             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

/anaconda3/envs/malicious_ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py in forward(self, input, target)
    940     def forward(self, input, target):
    941         return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
--> 942                                ignore_index=self.ignore_index, reduction=self.reduction)
    943 
    944 

/anaconda3/envs/malicious_ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction)
   2054     if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
   2055         reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 2056     return nll_loss(log_softmax(input, 1), target, weight, None, ignore_index, None, reduction)
   2057 
   2058 

/anaconda3/envs/malicious_ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in log_softmax(input, dim, _stacklevel, dtype)
   1348         dim = _get_softmax_dim('log_softmax', input.dim(), _stacklevel)
   1349     if dtype is None:
-> 1350         ret = input.log_softmax(dim)
   1351     else:
   1352         ret = input.log_softmax(dim, dtype=dtype)
```

/ ##################################################################### /

If you are interested in seeing the rest of my code, here it is:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.autograd import Variable


class LogisticRegressionModel(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, in_dim, num_classes):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(in_dim, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.linear(x)


class Train(LogisticRegressionModel):

    def __init__(self, in_dim, num_classes, lr, batch_size):
        super().__init__(in_dim, num_classes)
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.learning_rate = lr
        self.input_layer_dim = in_dim
        self.output_layer_dim = num_classes
        self.criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
        self.model = LogisticRegressionModel(self.input_layer_dim, self.output_layer_dim)
        self.device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
        self.model = self.model.to(self.device)
        self.optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(self.model.parameters(), lr = self.learning_rate)  

    def epochs(self, iterations, train_dataset, batch_size):
        epochs = int(iterations/(len(train_dataset)/batch_size))
        return epochs

    def train_model(self, training_data, n_iters):
        batch = self.batch_size
        epochs = self.epochs(n_iters, training_data, batch)
        training_data = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset = training_data, batch_size = batch, shuffle = True)

        for epoch in range(epochs):

            for i, data in enumerate(training_data):

                X_train = data[:, :-1]
                Y_train = data[:, -1]

                if torch.cuda.is_available():
                    x = Variable(torch.Tensor(X_train).cuda())
                    y = Variable(torch.Tensor(Y_train).cuda())

                else:
                    x = Variable(torch.Tensor(X_train.float()))
                    y = Variable(torch.Tensor(Y_train.float()))

                out = self.model(x)
                _, predicted = torch.max(out.data, 1)
                loss = self.criterion(predicted, y)
                self.optimizer.zero_grad()
                loss.backward()
                self.optimizer.step()

                if i % 100 == 0:
                    print('[{}/{}] Loss: {:.6f}'.format(epoch + 1, epochs, loss))
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems you are not quite using Cross Entropy Loss the way it is designed. CEL is primarily used for classification problems, where you have a probability distribution over some number of classes:

```
predicted = torch.tensor([[1,2,3,4]]).float()
```

(in this case, there are four classes, and the model is indicating its confidence of those four classes)

and then the target is simply an **index** indicating which class is correct:

```py
target = torch.tensor([1]).long()
```

then, we can compute:

```py
lossfxn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
loss = lossfxn(predicted, target)
print(loss) # outputs tensor(2.4402)
```

now, if we change the prediction to align with the target:

```py
predicted = torch.tensor([[1,10,3,4]]).float()
target = torch.tensor([1]).long()
lossfxn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
loss = lossfxn(predicted, target)
print(loss) # outputs tensor(0.0035)
```

now the loss is much lower, because the prediction is correct!

Please consider the loss functions available and determine which is appropriate for your task: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#loss-functions (perhaps MSELoss?)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, makes so much sense now. I know what I did wrong, in my full code if you look above you'll see there is a line in the ***train_model*** method of the **Train** class that attempts to find the maximum index of the predicted probabilities. Therefore, instead of it returning a distribution of probabilities it just returns an index of the maximum value in that array; hence, the tensor of integers. ***, predicted = torch.max(out.data, 1)*** I now get a tensor of probability distributions as you said. However, my loss is returned as nan. to be continued in the next comment....

Comment: When I examined the output of my model for that batch, I saw some rows with nan values, or some rows with all nan values. Does that explain why my loss is nan? What can I do about this? Should I just replace these values with 0 or the mean of that column even? Btw, this is a classification problem. I'm trying to classify urls as their type of malicious category.

Comment: Just tried replacing nans with zeros. Didn't work, because of the following ***RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn***. Any suggestions on how to move forward with this?

Comment: Hi, it seems that your question is now more "My model is producing NaNs, how do I fix this?" -- glancing over your code I don't see an immediate answer -- for a simple nn.Linear model like this, maybe you are sending NaNs in somehow? (I don't think I have access to your data) -- maybe use https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html?highlight=isnan#torch.isnan to check your data throughout the model? ` assert not torch.isnan(mytensor).any()` may be useful

Comment: Here's a link to my repo with the Jupyter Notebook and CSV. I've updated the code a little bit, but there's not much difference. Please have a look at it and let me know if you can't access it. Thanks alot. https://github.com/islamaymansais/Malicious-URL-Classifier/blob/master/Malicious%20URL%20classifier.ipynb

Comment: The dataset does contain nans upon importing, but i fill them up with zeros. That's my new update. Same error though.

Comment: Added issues to your github

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate you taking the time to do so!